# Express: serve Webpack bundle on subroutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I have built a web application with an Express back end and React front end.

Whenever a request is made to the Express server, it first checks whether the URL matches any of the backend routes, and if not, it sends the React bundle generated with Webpack to the client (where URL routing is handled by React Router).

This works fine for all basic routes. However, as soon as a request to a subroute is made (e.g. `/foo/bar`), Express serves `index.html` correctly, but seems to look for a directory `foo` to serve `bundle.js` from, which in this case is undesired behaviour, and results in an error because the file is not found there. For the JS file, this can be fixed by using a relative path, but the problem still exists for images, which are handled by Webpack.

Does anybody know a solution to this?

server.js:

```
server.listen(port, () => {
    // set up API routes
    server.use('/api/auth', require(...));
    server.use('/api/users', require(...));

    // serve public files (JavaScript bundle, images, etc.)
    server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client', 'public')));

    // serve index.html on all other routes
    server.get('*', (request, response) => {
        response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client', 'public', 'index.html'));
    });
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="/client-bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example of an image import in a React component:

```
import someIcon from '../public/img/someIcon.svg';
...
<img src={someIcon}>
```

Webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './client/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'client/public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
            { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]' }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
};
```

My file structure:

```
/app
    /client
        /components
            /SomeComponent.jsx
        /index.jsx
        /public
            /index.html
            /bundle.js
            /img
                /someIcon.svg
    /server
        /server.js
```

Comment: Simply use absolute path `src="/client-bundle.js"`

Comment: @Molda I have tried this, and it works for the JS file, but not for the images

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying in `src="???"` and where is the image in your folder structure?

Comment: @Molda I have updated my question with an example

Comment: what is the `src` on the client? In order for it to work `<img src={someIcon}>` must render to `<img src="/img/someIcon.svg">`

Comment: @Molda This path cannot be absolute, otherwise Webpack will not find the image. Or is there is a way to let Webpack generate absolute paths when bundling?

Comment: @Baleb Can you update you question with your production webpack configuration?

Comment: @Prakashsharma I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set public path of server in the webpack configuration. If you set public path then webpack will replace the paths of images and other files with that public path.In your wepack set public path as

```
output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'client/public'),
        publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
```

Also in your file loader you are setting `name=img/[name].[ext]`

So by above configuration your image paths will be replaced as

`http://localhost:3000/img/someIcon.svg`